# Is there a sublime text plugin to auto align CSS values?

Tags: plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a SublimeText plugin that converts the following:

```
font-style:normal;
font-weight:normal;
font-variant:normal;
```

Into:

```
font-style:   normal;
font-weight:  normal;
font-variant: normal;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Alignment](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_alignment) plugin for Sublime Text, which lets you use multiple cursors in order to align your statements. You can check out the [creator's site](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/alignment) for instructions on installing, customizing, and usage.

Answer (score 0):

I know [AlignTab](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AlignTab) can to this, I'm just not sure whether it does so automatically. If you know your RegEx, you can also have a look [AutoAligner](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AutoAligner).

Answer (score 0):

There's another new package that can do this: [Perfectionist](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Perfectionist)